AuthorizationHandler gets new instance of injected service
I have a Blazor app with custom AuthorizationHandler and IAuthorizationRequirement. Snippet from the AuthorizationHandler:
    internal class PermissionLevelAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<PermissionLevelRequirement>
    {
        private readonly AuthService _authService;


        public PermissionLevelAuthorizationHandler(AuthService authService)
        {
            _authService= authService;
        }

        protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, PermissionLevelRequirement requirement)
        {
            string? requiredResource = ((DefaultHttpContext?)context.Resource)?.Request.Path;
            int requiredLevel = requirement.Level;
            var canAccess = _authService.GetPermission(requiredResource, context.User, requiredLevel);
            if (canAccess) {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
        }
}

AuthorizationHandler has injected AuthService, which does two things:

Fetches from database all the groups that current user belongs to

Checks (again in database) if any of the user's groups can access the required page with required permission level.


Both AuthService and AuthorizationHandler are scoped services.
Since the AuthService has to do two queries for each authorization check, I wanted to store the current user permissions in the AuthService and only contact the database if I don't have the permissions loaded yet.
Problem: The problem is that it seems that AuthorizationHandler gets new instance of AuthService every time even though they are both scoped. Therefore I can't store any data in the service. Why is that and is there any way to fix that? Are there any better ways of doing that?
As far as I know the alternatives are:

store claims in the authentication cookie. That would reduce my service from doing 2 queries to doing only the second one. But the problem is, user can have many groups so the cookie can become too big.
store in browser's local storage or session storage. I would prefer not to store permissions there.
store permissions for all users in a singleton service and refresh them all periodically. That would work but I don't like the fact that the user would have to wait for the refresh after we change permissions.

Also, the authentication is done by a central app. So the authentication cookie is shared amongst multiple apps. Which makes storage a bit more complicated because I would have to handle deletion of data correctly on all apps. That's why it seems the best solution is to store data in DI service instance.

Try storing the data in a Transient scoped service? If this service can't be made transient, make another that you can inject into it.

Which Blazor mode are you using? Depending on the mode, the scoping behaves differently. The code seems to be server side code, or am I mistaken?

@BrianParker If I register AuthorizationHandler as singleton and AuthService as transient, I get the same instance of AuthService for all users - basically a singleton.

@cmos Blazor server, yes

Scopes in Blazor Server are, in general, persisted per connection.
However, if I understand the official documentation correctly (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-8.0#service-lifetime), there is an exception, which is
"circuit messages among components that are loaded on the client".
I'm assuming your logic is executed in the scope of these curcuit messages and therefore, the service instance of your scoped service is not persisted, which would explain the behavior you are experiencing.
I would suggest implementing a Singleton-Cache (like you already mentioned) to securely persist the data.
